# Locust Save response in a file

Tags: python, locust

I'm using the event hook "request_success" to store each response in a file.

```
class Print:  # pylint: disable=R0902
"""
Record every response (useful when debugging a single locust)
"""

def __init__(self, env: locust.env.Environment, include_length=False, include_time=False):
    self.env = env
    self.env.events.request_success.add_listener(self.request_success)

def request_success(self, request_type, name, response_time, response_length, **_kwargs):
    users = self.env.runner.user_count
    data = [datetime.now(), request_type, name, response_time, users]
    state_data.append(data)


@events.init.add_listener
def locust_init_listener(environment, **kwargs):
    Print(env=environment)


@events.quitting.add_listener
def write_statistics(environment, **kwargs):
    with open("output/requests_stats_u150_c.csv", "a+") as f:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(f)
            for row in state_data:
            csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

However, for multiple workers, some of the lines overlap, I even lost some of the lines. Here's the sample error response.

```
2021-03-18 17:08:28.019587,POST,login,262.42033099697437,50
2021-03-18 17:08:28.021776,POST,select_order,16.014199994970113,50
2021-03-18 17:08:28.028505,GET2021-03-18 17:08:28.030823,GET,home,3.924126998754218,50
```

The 3rd entry got corrupted by double entry. I guess both of the worker tried to write at once.

Any idea how can I store all successful responses in a multi-worker locust test?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on exactly what data you need. The workers already send all the request data to the master and the master has [built-in ability to save stats to CSV](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/retrieving-stats.html). If you need more than this, I would still have the master do it. Much easier to control writing to a file from one place than coordinate multiple.

You can use [`report_to_master`](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/api.html#locust.event.Events.report_to_master) event on the workers to add in whatever extra data you may need to be included in the payload reported to the master. Then on the master you can use [`worker_report`](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/api.html#locust.event.Events.worker_report) for the master to pull out the data from the worker payloads. I'd probably save it to some other variables on the master and then have another function periodically write the data to a file so there's no contention in writes. You could start the writing by using the [`init`](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/api.html#locust.event.Events.init) hook, spawn your own greenlet that writes the data and then sleeps for 2 seconds (that's the interval that workers report to master at).

Comment: As you can see, I'm using the "request_success" event. I need to store each successful request. Does the worker report all requests to the master or just aggregate stats?

Comment: I saw you were using `request_success`. The workers do aggregate stats but in a way that gives you almost exactly the same data as it appears you're recording. You get the name, method, total requests, total response time (sum of all requests' times), min and max times, failure count, and total response length (so you can calculate the average). I generally question the need for more than this. Non-aggregated stats for any sizable test are very hard to work with—too much data. Blows up memory, CPU usage, and storage for no good reason.

Comment: I see. Yes, after analyzing the CSV full history, I agree with you. the master periodically writes full history, and that is all I needed. I will just add more stats into that report by using "report to master" and worker report. thanks for your direction.